# SpringBoot/JPA - data row level authorization

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-security

I'm looking for a way to authorize access based on ROLES and DATA CONTENT (table row) using Spring Boot & JPA

The use case is the following:

```
Given a User with a Role 'ROLE_AAA'
When user fetches data from table 'REPORT'
Then only reports with specific 'REPORT_ROLE' association will be returned
```

**ER**

Table: role

| ID | ROLE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ROLE_AAA |
| 2 | ROLE_BBB |

Table: report

| ID | CONTENT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |
| 3 | ... |
| 4 | ... |
| 5 | ... |

Table: report_roles

| REPORT_ID | ROLE_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |

In this case a user with role ROLE_AAA will get reports with ID 1,2 & 5 only.

```
SELECT re.*
FROM report re
JOIN report_role rr
ON re.id = rr.report_id
JOIN role ro
ON ro.id = rr.role_id
WHERE ro.name = 'ROLE_AAA'
```

I could easily write queries (@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query) joining on table I want to get data from, with the association role table, but I feel I'm missing a JPA or Spring Security feature that might offer it out off the box.

Any design/implementation suggestion will be very appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Since returns will be paginated (`retuning Page<Object> from JPARepository`), I believe PostFiltering is not an option here.

Comment: Spring Security should operate at the API level and probably doesn't know about JPA, so that probably doesn't help here. JPA doesn't deal much with security so I'd also say you need to roll your own queries. As an alternative you might be able to intersect queries or entities being returned and apply the filters there but custom queries are likely to be the easier to understand and thus maintain approach (entities might be bypassed and queries probably too, e.g. via `findById()`).

Comment: I agree with Thomas. However, if you insist on using Spring Security and don't mind the data actually being read into the application you could use a [`@PostFilter`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-prefilter-postfilter)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an older article I wrote on the subject of using [@Pre/Post annotations with a custom `PermissionEvaluator`](https://insource.io/blog/articles/custom-authorization-with-spring-boot.html). It seems your best bet here, and allows you to purely use annotations instead of custom queries. Of course, it only works if there aren't too many reports being returned from your query (without a `ro.name = 'ROLE_AAA'` filter).

In your case however, you aren't really trying to use the `hasPermission(filterObject, 'xyz')` syntax because your use case is role-based, meaning permissions are **roles** and are already in the authentication object (e.g. authorities) and the database (e.g. `report_roles`). With a M:N relationship between user roles and report roles, you can implement a helper to do the check for you, like this:

```java
@RestController
public class ReportsController {
    @GetMapping("/reports")
    @PostFilter("@reportExpressions.hasAnyRole(filterObject, authentication)")
    public List<Report> getReports() {
        return new ArrayList<>(List.of(
            new Report("Report #1", Set.of("ROLE_AAA", "ROLE_BBB")),
            new Report("Report #2", Set.of("ROLE_AAA", "ROLE_CCC"))
        ));
    }

    @Component("reportExpressions")
    public static class ReportExpressions {
        public boolean hasAnyRole(Report report, Authentication authentication) {
            Set<String> authorities = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(
                authentication.getAuthorities());
            return report.getRoles().stream().anyMatch(authorities::contains);
        }
    }

    public static class Report {
        private final String name;
        private final Set<String> roles;

        public Report(String name, Set<String> roles) {
            this.name = name;
            this.roles = roles;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public Set<String> getRoles() {
            return roles;
        }
    }
}
```

If the current user has `ROLE_AAA`, they will see both reports, etc. My example uses a controller, but you can apply the same annotation to a JPA repository.

Comment: Nice article, but since I'm dealing with pagination (I just included this extra information in my post) I believe PostFiltering is not an option

Comment: See [integration with Spring Data](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#data) in the Spring Security reference docs. You can access `authentication` and `principal` for example in your queries. But I'm not sure how to build a query if your roles are many-valued and your `authentication.authorities` are also many valued (e.g. M:N). If you just wanted to pull a single role/authority out and query on that, you might get away with a JPA query like `select r from Report r where ?#{ @reportExpressions.extractRole(authentication) } member of r.roles and ...`.